# EF Core ToDictionary throw expression could not be translated

Tags: linq, dictionary, entity-framework-core

I have this query:

```
        Project = await Context.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == project.Id)
        .Select(x => new ProjectModel
        {
            Id = project.Id,
            Name = project.Name,                
            TreeDataDict = x.Tasks.Select(y => new TreeItemModel()
            {
                NodeId = y.Id,
                ParentId = SetTaskParentId(y, y.Type),
                NodeTitle = y.Name,
                Expanded = false,
                Object = new TaskBaseModel
                {
                    Milestone = y.Milestone,
                    StartDate = y.StartDate,
                    CurrentEndDate = y.CurrentEndDate,
                    EndDate = y.EndDate,
                },
                Icon = TaskHelper.GetTaskIcon(y.Type),
                Children = new List<TreeItemModel>()
            }).ToDictionary(y => y.NodeId, y => y)                              
        }).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

and also tried like this:

```
        Project = await Context.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == project.Id)
        .Select(x => new ProjectModel
        {
            Id = project.Id,
            Name = project.Name,                
            TreeDataDict = x.Tasks.ToDictionary(y => y.Id, y => new TreeItemModel(
            {
                NodeId = y.Id,
                ParentId = SetTaskParentId(y, y.Type),
                NodeTitle = y.Name,
                Expanded = false,
                Object = new TaskBaseModel
                {
                    Milestone = y.Milestone,
                    StartDate = y.StartDate,
                    CurrentEndDate = y.CurrentEndDate,
                    EndDate = y.EndDate,
                },
                Icon = TaskHelper.GetTaskIcon(y.Type),
                Children = new List<TreeItemModel>()
            })                              
        }).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Both ways I got this exception:

[image]

What could be causing this? and is there a way I could make this work without fetching as a list and then covert it to dictionary? What could be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Regards

Comment: I think there is no usefull way around fetching a list first and then converting ist to a dictionary. What the exception tells you is that EF can't translate the query you wrote to SQL which makes sense as `Dictionary` is a .NET type which does not exist in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be causing this?

Translation of the nested `ToDictionary` call (none of the available overloads) is not supported. Consider it one of the (many) current (latest at the time of writing official v5.0.11) EF Core shortcomings.

Interestingly though, the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` constructor overload with `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` argument as well as projection (`Select`) to `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` *is* supported, which gives the workaround - replace the `ToDictionary` call with the aforementioned constructor and `Select`, e.g. (replace `int` with the type of the `Id`)

```cs
TreeDataDict = new Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel>(
x.Tasks.Select(y => new TreeItemModel()
{
    NodeId = y.Id,
    ParentId = SetTaskParentId(y, y.Type),
    NodeTitle = y.Name,
    Expanded = false,
    Object = new TaskBaseModel
    {
        Milestone = y.Milestone,
        StartDate = y.StartDate,
        CurrentEndDate = y.CurrentEndDate,
        EndDate = y.EndDate,
    },
    Icon = TaskHelper.GetTaskIcon(y.Type),
    Children = new List<TreeItemModel>()
})
.Select(e => new KeyValuePair<int, TreeItemModel>(e.NodeId, e)));
```

This will fix the current error. But note that you are using other non-translatable constructs (custom method calls like `SetTaskParentId(y, y.Type)` and `TaskHelper.GetTaskIcon(y.Type)`) which are supported only in the final `Select`, so make sure to *not* add LINQ operator like `Where`, `OrderBy` etc. after the root query `Select(x => new ProjectModel { ... }`, otherwise you'll get other runtime errors. `ToList`, `First

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, was wondering if there was a way with only one Select..

Comment: Sure, you can modify your original select and do directly `y => new KeyValuePair<...>(y.Id, new TreeItemModel() { ... }))`. But I did it this way to keep it closer to the original construct. And multiple LINQ selects don't really matter when the LINQ query is translated to SQL, since the translator will consolidate them as if they were single select (as you can see in the generated SQL).

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful